# List of strings to binary parse tree representation

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tree, nltk

Assume I have a binary tree in bracketed representation as follows:

```
best_parse = "(ROOT (S (S (S (S (S Our) (S intent)) (S is)) (S (S to) (S (S promote) (S (S (S the) (S best)) (S alternative))))) (S (S he) (S says))))"
```

I can get the spans (constituents) out of it using the `tree_to_spans` method, which gives me **`[(0, 2), (0, 3), (5, 7), (5, 8), (4, 8), (3, 8), (0, 8), (8, 10)]`**

```
import nltk
import collections

def tree_to_spans(tree):
    if isinstance(tree, str):
        tree = nltk.Tree.fromstring(tree)
    length = len(tree.pos())
    queue = collections.deque(tree.treepositions())
    stack = [(queue.popleft(), 0)]
    j = 0
    spans = []
    while stack != []:
        (p, i) = stack[-1]
        if not queue or queue[0][:-1] != p:
            if isinstance(tree[p], nltk.tree.Tree):
                if j - i > 1:
                    spans.append((tree[p].label(), (i, j)))
            else:
                j = i + 1
            stack.pop()
        else:
            q = queue.popleft()
            stack.append((q, j))
    return spans
```

I can also get the string corresponding to the span using `get_constituents` method, which gives me ALL CONSTITUENTS of the tree.

**`['Our intent', 'Our intent is', 'the best', 'the best alternative', 'promote the best alternative', 'to promote the best alternative', 'Our intent is to promote the best alternative', 'he says', 'Our intent is to promote the best alternative he says']`**

```
def get_constituents(sample_string):
    t = nltk.Tree.fromstring(sample_string)
    spans = evaluate.tree_to_spans(t)
    sentence = " ".join(item[0] for item in t.pos()).split()
    constituents = [" ".join(sentence[span[0]: span[1]])for span in spans]
    # Add original sentence
    constituents = constituents + [" ".join(sentence)]
    return constituents
```

**PROBLEM:** I am stuck at converting it back to the tree (like the one shown at the beginning) given a list of ALL CONSTITUENTS. Basically, reverse engineering. Assume the sentence is given:

```
s = "Our intent is to promote the best alternative he says"
```

**Edit**

Assume certain elements can be deleted from the list (parts). For eg -

```
parts = [
    'Our intent', 
    'the best', 
    'the best alternative', 
    'promote the best alternative', 
    'to promote the best alternative', 
    'Our intent is to promote the best alternative', 
    'Our intent is to promote the best alternative he says'
]
```

Here, `"He says"` and `"Our intent is"` have been removed from the list. I want to get the tree structure in the same format as above, except the ones for the deleted constituents.

Another way to look at it is:

consider, we have the spans -

```
spans = [(0, 2), (0, 3), (5, 7), (5, 8), (4, 8), (3, 8), (0, 8), (8, 10)]
```

I delete `(0, 3)` and `(8, 10)`.

I want to put brackets over, like this:

```
(((0  1  2)  (3  (4  ((5  6  7)  8))))  9  10)
```

Then, we can map the index with the corresponding string.

**EDIT-2**

For instance, if we were to remove ONLY `"he says"` and `"Our intent is"` from the parts, our final tree in bracketed form should look like:

```
"(ROOT (S (S (S (S (S Our) (S intent)) (S is) (S (S to) (S (S promote) (S (S (S the) (S best)) (S alternative)))))(S he) (S says))))")
```

Another instance, if we were to remove ONLY `"to promote the best alternative",` and `"Our intent is to promote the best alternative"` from the parts, our final tree in bracketed form should look like:

```
"(ROOT (S (S (S Our) (S intent)) (S is)) (S to) (S (S promote) (S (S (S the) (S best)) (S alternative))) (S (S he) (S says)))"
```

We can assume that the full-sentence `"Our intent is to promote the best alternative he says"` will NEVER be deleted. This is also TRUE for single-words in the sentence, just to give you a background.

Comment: Looking now at your edit-2: It seems like the first example has a desired output that is a non-binary tree. The node with "is" has a left and a right sibling, and the same goes for the node with "he". It was my understanding (from the title) that you were looking for generating a *binary* tree. This changes the question drastically :/

Comment: Cool, I have created a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65476660/9775417) for you to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would iterate the constituents in reversed order, so to get an in-order traversal of the tree (with the right side traversed before the left side). So in this solution I assume the order of constituents is given in the same order as you get them from your code.

With recursion you can then rebuild each subtree recursively:

```
def to_tree(parts):
    i = len(parts) - 1

    def recur(part, expect=False):
        nonlocal i
        words = part.split()
        if len(words) == 1:  # leaf
            return "(S {})".format(words[0])
        if expect and i > 0 and parts[i-1] == part:
            i -= 1
        if len(words) == 2:  # 2 leaves
            return "(S (S {}) (S {}))".format(*words)
        i -= 1
        nextpart = parts[i]
        if part.endswith(" " + nextpart):
            right = recur(nextpart)
            left = recur(part[0:-len(nextpart)-1], True)
        elif part.startswith(nextpart + " "):
            right = recur(part[len(nextpart)+1:], True)
            left = recur(nextpart)
        else: 
            sides = part.split(" " + nextpart + " ")
            assert len(sides) == 2, "Could not parse input" 
            right = recur(sides[1], True)
            left = recur(sides[0], True)
        return "(S {} {})".format(left, right)
            
    return "(ROOT {})".format(recur(parts[i]))
```

The example could be run as:

```
parts = [
    'Our intent', 
    'Our intent is', 
    'the best', 
    'the best alternative', 
    'promote the best alternative', 
    'to promote the best alternative', 
    'Our intent is to promote the best alternative', 
    'he says', 
    'Our intent is to promote the best alternative he says'
]

print(to_tree(parts))
```

...which would output your original string.

As per your edit, the above code can "survive" some removals from the input. For example 'Our intent is' and 'he says' can be removed from the input, and the output will still be the same. But there are limitations. If too much is removed, the tree cannot be rebuilt any more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mean, I should have made it clearer in the question before. I plan to modify the list (parts) by deleting certain elements. You can assume a couple of elements being deleted. I still want to maintain the same tree structure, of course, excluding the deleted items (constituents). Edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: By deleting some constituents you risk to remove information that will make it impossible to still reconstruct the tree. This solution assumes that the constituents are given in pre-order, and none of the entries are single words, as those words can be silently assumed.

Comment: In your edit, how would the algo know that "our intent" should be siblings and not "intent is"?

Comment: Edited my question again. I think this would be easier to follow.

Comment: I tried running the script. But when we delete "he says", "Our intent is", it shouldn't be part of the constituents. `get_constituents()` function returns the same list of constituents as before even after removal. Can you see my recent edit on working with spans instead. It is much easier to comprehend.

Comment: It was my understanding you wanted those parts. Oh well, I now need a night's sleep. I will come back to it tomorrow. I don't want to revert to the spans, since you said the constituents would be the only input. So it must be clear from the constituents what should happen May I ask you to edit the question, and add at least 5 examples of input and corresponding output, so that there will be no more misunderstanding?

Comment: Alright, I hope the recent edit with the shown examples makes sense better. Please let me know if it does.