# Select Constituents to parse tree representation

Tags: python, string, nltk

Consider we have the spans, corresponding to the sentence,

```
s = "Our intent is to promote the best alternative he says"
spans = [(0, 2), (0, 3), (5, 7), (5, 8), (4, 8), (3, 8), (0, 8), (8, 10)]
```

I delete `(0, 3)` and `(8, 10)`.

I want to put brackets over, like this:

```
(((0  1  2)  (3  (4  ((5  6  7)  8))))  9  10)
```

where 0, 1, ... , 10 are the indices of single-words of the sentence.

For instance, if we were to remove ONLY `"he says"` and `"Our intent is"`. Here, the span of "Our intent is" corresponds to `(0, 3)`, and the span of "he says" corresponds to `(8, 10)`. Our final tree in bracketed form should look like this:

```
"(ROOT (S (S (S (S (S Our) (S intent)) (S is) (S (S to) (S (S promote) (S (S (S the) (S best)) (S alternative)))))(S he) (S says))))")
```

Another instance, if we were to remove ONLY `"to promote the best alternative"`, and `"Our intent is to promote the best alternative"`, Our final tree in bracketed form should look like this:

```
"(ROOT (S (S (S Our) (S intent)) (S is)) (S to) (S (S promote) (S (S (S the) (S best)) (S alternative))) (S (S he) (S says)))"
```

We can assume that the full-sentence "Our intent is to promote the best alternative he says" will NEVER be deleted. This is also TRUE for single-words in the sentence, just to give you a background.

I am looking for a way in which we can achieve either/both of

1. bracketed representation over indices given spans.
2. bracketed string tree representation with the start symbol, "S" denoting a non-terminal node.

Comment: What is the question? ;-)

Comment: It looks like the first bracketed form does not have the same grouping as the string form. For instance, in the first I see `(1 2 3)` in one group, but in the second I see `(S (S (S Our) (S intent)) (S is))`, and so 1 and 2 are grouped first... How does this represent the same thing?

Comment: They need not have to match. It was purely for illustration purposes. I am keener to get the bracketed tree representation. Let me know if you have understood what is expected.

Comment: OK, so input is string + spans, and output is bracketed tree representation, right?

Comment: @trincot: do you need more clarity on this, or you've figured it out?

Comment: I think I understand. Will come back if you bump into something else.

Comment: ok, if so, can you please write an answer?

Comment: In the first tree representation, the first two `(S ` encompass the whole expression. Is that immediate "grandchild" intended? Or should there be one fewer `(S ... )`?

Comment: On the other hand, the second tree does not have an all-encompassing `(S ...)`. Shouldn't there be at least one to combine the two children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the spans are given in pre-order (when traversing the tree), I would do a reverse iteration (in-order, with children visited in reversed order). When a span has no overlap with the previously visited span, then they represent siblings, otherwise they have a parent-child relationship. This can be used to steer the recursion in a recursive algorithm. There is also a loop to allow for an arbitrarily number of children (the tree is not necessarily binary):

```
def to_tree(phrase, spans):
    words = phrase.split()
    iter = reversed(spans)
    current = None

    def encode(start, end):
        return ["(S {})".format(words[k]) for k in range(end - 1, start - 1, -1)]
        
    def recur(start, end, tab=""):
        nonlocal current
        nodes = []
        current = next(iter, None)
        while current and current[1] > start:  # overlap => it's a child
            child_start, child_end = current
            assert child_start >= start and child_end <= end, "Invalid spans"
            # encode what comes at the right of this child (single words):
            nodes.extend(encode(child_end, end))
            # encode the child itself using recursion
            nodes.append(recur(child_start, child_end, tab+"  "))
            end = child_start
        nodes.extend(encode(start, end))
        return "(S {})".format(" ".join(reversed(nodes))) if len(nodes) > 1 else nodes[0]

    return "(ROOT {})".format(recur(0, len(words)))
```

You would call it like so:

```
phrase = "Our intent is to promote the best alternative he says"
spans = [(0, 2), (0, 3), (5, 7), (5, 8), (4, 8), (3, 8), (0, 8), (8, 10)]
print(to_tree(phrase, spans))
```

The output is not exactly the same for the examples you have given. This code will never produce a nested like  `(S (S ... ))`, which would represent a node with exactly one child. In that case this code will just generate one level `(S ... )`. On the other hand, the root will always start out with a `(S ... )` that wraps all other nodes.

Comment: I want to follow up on this - Is it possible to create a tree with duplicated spans? It could be non-binary, for instance? What sort of modification is needed to achieve if it is the case?

Comment: In the mean time my mind has been on numerous other subjects. If you have a follow-up question, please consider posting it as a new question. You can of course refer to this question in there. If no-one answers, I may have a look at it later.